# Crontab not running extended mySql restart command in Docker container

Tags: cron

Good day all,

I have a Docker Container with Ubuntu OS and mySql installed.

I need to restart the mySql once a day and would normally use cron to do this.

When I run the script via the CLI the scripts runs perfectly within the Docker Container.

**Script contents:**
#!/bin/bash

echo "Stopping MySQL"
service mysql stop
sleep 15s
echo "Starting MySQL"
service mysql start
sleep 10s
echo "MySql Restarted"
service mysql status
sleep 10s

**Log when running from CLI, using ./mysqlRestart >>/var/log/mysqlRestart 2>&1:**
Stopping MySQL

- Stopping MySQL database server mysqld
  ...done.
  Starting MySQL
- Starting MySQL database server mysqld
  su: warning: cannot change directory to /nonexistent: No such file or directory
  ...done.
  MySql Restarted
- /usr/bin/mysqladmin  Ver 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
  Copyright (c) 2000, 2022, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Server version          8.0.30-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
Protocol version        10
Connection              Localhost via UNIX socket
UNIX socket             /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Uptime:                 11 sec

Threads: 2  Questions: 8  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 119  Flush tables: 3  Open tables: 38  Queries per second avg: 0.727

**crontab -e entry:**
*/5 * * * * bash /usr/local/bin/mysqlRestart >>/var/log/mysqlRestart 2>&1

**Log when running from crontab:**
Stopping MySQL
/usr/local/bin/mysqlRestart: line 4: service: command not found
Starting MySQL
/usr/local/bin/mysqlRestart: line 7: service: command not found
MySql Restarted
/usr/local/bin/mysqlRestart: line 10: service: command not found